# Mysql remote server with rights to WMI

Tags: networking, windows-8, mysql, remote, wmi

I just fixed and got my **MySQL** running on my computer on port forwarded with all the grants.

However, when I am enabling remote server Windows asks for user login information for **WMI** I need to enter user and password.  But the problem is that I am running Windows 8, and the account has a first name and surname!

How do I get a username if it's two words, when it must only require one word?

unless **WMI** does not need my Windows 8 login information. Then what do I type in? I did try the root user did not work. I do know my windows 8 password.

**UPDATE**

**PROBLEM**
I get could not connect to target machine. Could not setup connection. Any idea why it does not work then? i am 100% sure my password is correct i tested it few times. Maybe you know what could be wrong?

**INFOMRATION HOW I CONNECT**
I have bind-address = 0.0.0.0 set in my.ini and default port forwarded on my router that i could connect outside network. In connections manager i have localhost host and my local ip(192.168.0.11) with user root and password with GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES that i could have access outside network. The thing that is left that it would work i need to Configure Remote Management like its showing me in this video: [YOUTUBE LINK](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DCgRF4KOYIY) soo i start doing the Configure Remote Management on my local ip that is set in connection manager (connection works) on part 2 that is Test DB Connection its a success no problems. This what i get in part 2: (v) Open Database Connection (v) Server version: 5.6.23-log (v) Server OS: unknown (database connection tested successfully) i go to part 3 now and then i select the 1 one that is: Native Windows Remote Management(windows only) not ssh login based managment. Now in part 4 that is Management AND OS a new login window pop up that say: Please enter a Windows user login and password for the remote server with rights to WMI. Service is saying: wmi@192.168.0.11 and wants me to enter username and password. That i guess is my windows 8 login information soo i type my windows 8 username and my password correctly and it gives me a error that is my problem. Error say: Could not setup connection. Could not connect to target machine. What i am doing wrong then? it would be nice to solve this problem here without making me make another question with the same text. Thanks. That is the best i can explain about my new problem. I did try using mysql user account that is root and mypassword. Still Could not setup connection. I hope you can help me fix this. I need it fixed its very important to me. Thanks again.

Comment: I get could not connect to target machine. Could not setup connection. Any idea why it does not work then? i am 100% sure my password is correct i tested it few times. Maybe you know what could be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your user name is stored in an environment variable.

If you open a cmd windows (start run cmd) you can enter the following command to find out your user name:

```
echo %username%
```

Example

```
C:\test>echo %username%
DavidPostill

C:\test>
```

Source [Windows Environment Variables](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-variables.html)

#### Further reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) is an excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.

Comment: Ok. But it seems to not be working. I get could not connect to target machine. Could not setup connection. Any idea why it does not work then? i am 100% sure my password is correct i tested it few times. Maybe you know what could be wrong?

Comment: I don't know about the rest of your problem. I answered "how do i get my user name that i have on windows 8?" ... the rest of your question is not very clear (at least I don't understand it). You should think about how you can explain your problem in a better way.

Comment: I will mark this as a answer soon. Today.